# Prevent RandomizedSearchCV from predicting KNN Classifier with all one class

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using RandomizedSearchCV & KNeighborsClassifier to try and predicut a loan default.

Using RandomizedSearchCV is seems great in theory but when I put it to the test it finds the best best_esimator_ to be one that predicts all the same labels.

(the data is split 75% PAID 25% Defaulted) so I am getting an accuracy of 75% but it is just predicting all PAID.

```
n_neighbors = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = len(X_train)/3, num = 5)]
weights = ['uniform', 'distance']
algorithm  = ["auto","ball_tree","kd_tree","brute"]
leaf_size  = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(10, 100, num = 5)]
p  = [1,2]       

random_grid = {'n_neighbors': n_neighbors,
               'weights': weights,
               'algorithm': algorithm,
               'leaf_size': leaf_size,
               'p': p}

knn_clf = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = knn_clf, param_distributions = random_grid, n_iter = 25, cv = 3, verbose=1,)
knn_random.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Is there anything I can do to combat this? Is there a paramater I can pass to stop this from happening? Or is there something I can do within my data?

y_test:

```
38        PAIDOFF
189       PAIDOFF
140       PAIDOFF
286    COLLECTION
142       PAIDOFF
101       PAIDOFF
187       PAIDOFF
139       PAIDOFF
149       PAIDOFF
11        PAIDOFF
269    COLLECTION
231       PAIDOFF
258       PAIDOFF
84        PAIDOFF
242       PAIDOFF
344    COLLECTION
104       PAIDOFF
214       PAIDOFF
109       PAIDOFF
76        PAIDOFF
41        PAIDOFF
262    COLLECTION
125       PAIDOFF
107       PAIDOFF
27        PAIDOFF
14        PAIDOFF
92        PAIDOFF
194       PAIDOFF
113       PAIDOFF
333    COLLECTION
          ...    
320    COLLECTION
15        PAIDOFF
72        PAIDOFF
122       PAIDOFF
243       PAIDOFF
184       PAIDOFF
294    COLLECTION
280    COLLECTION
218       PAIDOFF
197       PAIDOFF
133       PAIDOFF
143       PAIDOFF
179       PAIDOFF
249       PAIDOFF
80        PAIDOFF
331    COLLECTION
137       PAIDOFF
103       PAIDOFF
120       PAIDOFF
248       PAIDOFF
5         PAIDOFF
236       PAIDOFF
219       PAIDOFF
322    COLLECTION
283    COLLECTION
135       PAIDOFF
124       PAIDOFF
293    COLLECTION
166       PAIDOFF
85        PAIDOFF
```

prediction:

```
array(['PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF',
       'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF',
       'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF',
       'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF',
       'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF',
       'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF',
       'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF',
       'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF',
       'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF',
       'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF',
       'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF',
       'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF',
       'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF',
       'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF',
       'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF',
       'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF',
       'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF',
       'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a classic problem of Imbalanced data. A couple of simple things that you can try is to upsample the minority class or downsample the majority class and try again. 
A better way would be to change your algorithm and use a SVC or a Neural Network
that could weight the loss for the minority cases highly.

For example, the sklearn `sklearn.svm.SVC` has `class_weights = 'balanced'` parameter that will help in this. It will basically weight the cost for minority classes with the ratio of those guys in the input data.

> The “balanced” mode uses the values of y to automatically adjust
>   weights inversely proportional to class frequencies in the input data
>   as